# Is this circular dependency a bad thing? Any potential problems?

Tags: c#, architecture

Here's the class I ended up with while building some data layer:

```
public class DataRequest
{
  public class DataResponse
  {
    public DataResponse(DataRequest req) { Request = req; }

    public DataRequest Request {get; set;}
    // ... here go some other fields ...
  }

  public Response { get; set; }

  public DataRequest()
  {
    Response = new DataResponse(this);
  }

  public void Execute()
  {
     ... Get some data and fill Response object ...
  }

}
```

I need request to be aware of response because it fills it with data; I need response to be aware of request because when I pass response to some other methods I want to have access to original request.

Do you see any potential problems with this architecture, like memory leaks, etc. or is it simply a bad design idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That doesn't look too evil, but you could also create a "DataContext" (for want of a better word) that exposes both the request and response, and only have each know about the context? i.e. to ask about the request the response would ask about:

```
this.Context.Request.SomeProperty;
```

It isn't a memory problem though; .NET doesn't do reference counting, so you don't need to worry about an island of circular references. If they are all unreachable *from other objects*, they'll get collected. The scenario in the question won't cause the world to end.

Comment: That's basically what I was thinking, much like ASP.NET keeps the HttpContext with Request and Response objects.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll consider your idea

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to make a manager class holding both the request and the response properties , it will give you omore control than this

```
public class DataManager
{
   public DataRequest Request {get; set;}
   public DataResponse Response {get; set;}


  public void Excute () 
{
//do you logic here 
}

}
```